# What is the meaning of size of the image?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Say I am standing at a distance of $20m$ from a plane mirror and looking at it. My image in it as I see it is smaller than how I perceive myself. Why then does my physics textbook tell me that in a plane mirror the size of the object is equal to the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

It means that relative to a curved mirror, i.e. No magnification, the plane mirror acts to not change the object.

Answer (score 0):

If I stood 40 m away from you, I'd look smaller than you, but I'm actually about the same size as you are.

Similarly your image in the mirror is 40 m away, so it looks small even though it is actually exactly the same size as you are.

Answer (score 0):

From the viewpoint of the mirror the object (you) and your image are the same size.

From your point of view your image in the mirror and an object which is the same size as you are which is placed next to the image, would both appear to be the same size.